# asp.net mvc 3 T4 View Template access property meta data (DisplayName, Description, UIHint) etc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, t4

Assume a strongly Typed View. What I want is to produce custom reusable T4 Templates for Create, Edit, Details, Delete List.

I want to control the markup and CSS based on the Property Meta Data (Data Annotations) I am having difficulty accessing and reading this int the T4 template. I am also having issues debugging the template I am looking at attempting to do this in a separate project currently as I cannot get it to fire in VS.NET 2010 currently, In theory something similar to the below code should be usable I ha

```
bool Scaffold(PropertyInfo property) {
    foreach (object attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes(true)) {
        var scaffoldColumn = attribute as ScaffoldColumnAttribute;
        if (scaffoldColumn != null && !scaffoldColumn.Scaffold) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tangible T4 editor licensed helped with the intellisense which helped get at the attributes, I haven't found a debug solution.

Comment: altered to keep stackoverflows smart ass labels at bay, how is it tumbleweed if not one answer it of autobigoraphy if because of this you answer your own question